# Fotorama Slider not displaying correctly on Initial Load

Tags: jquery, slider, fotorama

We are using the fotorama slider on this site: http://kitchensglasgow.co.uk/contemporary-kitchens.html

Unfortunately, on the initial page load the slider displays in a small area in the top left corner of the container, but when you refresh the browser it expands and displays correctly.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated,

Thanks,

Andy

Comment: I can't reproduce that. What versions of OS / Browser are you using?

Comment: I can reproduce with Win/Firefox. Not the solution, but you have a js-error on your site coming from the site.js. There is an ajax form function calling jquery.tabs() which is missing. You should load jquery.js first. tabs() is a jquery.ui widget and currently you don't include jquery.ui. You can download it from http://jqueryui.com/ In your html, first include jquery.js, then the ui, then the site.js etc. In addition, you're also loading the missing img http://kitchensglasgow.co.uk/contemporary-kitchens481b.jpg (just noticed in the net console)

Comment: Thankyou for helping guys I decided to switch to a different plugin (flexslider) which seems to be working better.

Answer (score 0):

I know you will not use it, since you change plugin, but can help someone else.

I had the same problem with the same plugin, but the problem was not from the plugin, but from the IIS. One day after this.

In my case, just have to add the ~ sign in my path to the image.

ex: src="~/Data/Images/nameofimage.png"